# Interpolation Issue in [style.background]

Tags: angular

Issue - I am trying to Interpolate the Json image at artist.images[0].url, but getting an error.

Error - NG5002: Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 32 in ['url(' + {{artist.images[0].url}} + ') no-repeat center center']

Image url works but not when interpolated

Works

```
<mat-card
    [style.background]="'url(' + 'https://i.scdn.co/image/a402db0dbd2b33ca7141ea0fd31e4b81e178c39a' + ') no-repeat center center'"
    [style.background-size]="'cover'" [style.height]="'450px'">
</mat-card>
```

Does Not work

```
<mat-card
    [style.background]="'url(' + {{artist.images[0].url}} + ') no-repeat center center'"
    [style.background-size]="'cover'" [style.height]="'450px'">
</mat-card>
```

Comment: Remove the curly brackets.

Comment: Feels dumb, Thanks @Phix

Comment: Happens to all of us at some point. Just remember if you're using `[]` in the attribute, there's no need to use interpolation in the attribute value. Same goes for strings, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're already doing a binding.

```
<mat-card
  [style.background]="'url(' + artist.images[0].url + ') no-repeat center center'"
  [style.background-size]="'cover'" [style.height]="'450px'">
</mat-card>
```